# What optimization algorithms are used in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Gradient descent is one of the well-known optimisation algorithms. However, are the regression algorithms in scikit-learn implemented with gradient descent or some other techniques?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple approaches to optimization in scikit-learn. I will focus on generalized linear models, where a vector of coefficients needs to be estimated:

- LinearRegression and Ridge use closed-form solution $\beta=(X^TX+I\lambda)^{-1}X^TY$, but Ridge can also use stochastic gradient descent or method of conjugate gradients
- Lasso and ElasticNet use [coordinate descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent)
- OrthogonalMatchingPursuit uses a greedy algorithm with the same name, that has $L_0$ penalty on coefficients
- ARDRegression and BayesianRidge use something like EM algorithm
- SGDRegressor and PassiveAggressiveRegressor use guess what! Stochastic gradient descent.
- HuberRegressor uses BFGS (a second-order optimization method)